# Copying all files in SSIS without Foreach

Tags: ssis

Is it possible to copy all the files from one folder to another without using foreach?

I have source as c:\test1*.txt

and destination as c:\test2

When I execute this using File System Task, I get the following error

```
 An error occurred with the following error message: "Illegal characters in path.".
```

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it's possible to copy **all** files from one folder to another.  Below, my source is C:\test1 and my destination is C:\test2.  The task below will copy **all** files from C:\test1 to C:\test2.

[image]

The error you are getting is due to the asterisk in your source.  Are you trying to use a wildcard?  The File System Task doesn't allow wildcards.  Check out the documentation on the [File System Task](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140185.aspx), below is an excerpt:

> The File System task operates on a single file or directory.
> Therefore, **this task does not support the use of wildcard characters**
> to perform the same operation on multiple files. To have the File
> System task repeat an operation on multiple files or directories, put
> the File System task in a Foreach Loop container, as described in the
> following steps:
>
> - **Configure the Foreach Loop container**   On the Collection page of the
>   Foreach Loop Editor, set the enumerator to Foreach File Enumerator and
>   enter the wildcard expression as the enumerator configuration for
>   Files. On the Variable Mappings page of the Foreach Loop Editor, map a
>   variable that you want to use to pass the file names one at a time to
>   the File System task.
> - **Add and configure a File System task**   Add a
>   File System task to the Foreach Loop container. On the General page of
>   the File System Task Editor, set the SourceVariable or
>   DestinationVariable property to the variable that you defined in the
>   Foreach Loop container.

The other option is to write a copy routine in a Script Task:

```cs
string fileName = string.Empty;
string destFile = string.Empty;
string sourcePath = @"C:\test1";
string targetPath = @"C:\test2";   

// Create a new target folder, if necessary. 
if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
}

if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
{
    string wildcard = "*.txt";
    string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, wildcard);

    // Copy the files and overwrite destination files if they already exist. 
    foreach (string s in files)
    {
        fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);
        destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
        System.IO.File.Copy(s, destFile, true);
    }
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("Source path does not exist!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking out time in answering this. So to speak, its not possible to do such kind of operation WITHOUT using Foreach.

Comment: You misunderstand... it _is_ possible (and easier) to do it in an execute process task.

Answer (score 3):

Or an execute process task with this in it:

```
COPY c:\test1*.txt c:\test2
```

This code is 25x more efficient at reducing keyboard wear than a script task. :p