# SSIS Expression wildcards

Tags: ssis, ssis-2008

I am trying to create file system task to copy some back up files from one server to another. Issue I am having is the end string is time stamp so can change day to day.

So I want to ignore characters passed the date. The Variable i have so far is

```
"\\\\192.168.100.201\\f\\Backups\\582499_backup_" 
+ (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "yyyy" , getdate() ) + "_"
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "mm" , getdate() ), 2) 
 + "_"
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "dd" , getdate() ), 2) 
+".bak"
```

This returns

> \192.168.100.201\f\Backups\582499_backup_2016_12_07.bak

The actual file is names 582499_backup_2016_12_07_030001_7282785.bak

So I need to ignore everything passed the 07. However I cant seem to get it working. I've tried following

[SQL Central](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1312477-364-1.aspx)

It errors giving the error

> [File System Task] Error: An error occurred with the following error
>   message: "Could not find file
>   '\192.168.100.201\f\Backups\582499_backup_2016_12_07.bak'.".

Comment: I often find the execute process task more useful. Here's an example of using execute process to move a bunch of files using widlcards: https://mitchellpearson.com/2015/06/05/move-files-in-ssis-using-execute-process-task/ You can copy instead by using COPY instead of move. Here's another sample: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23158909/copying-all-files-in-ssis-without-foreach

Answer (score 0):

I usually have different variables for different locations/file signatures I want to process/move, etc. Try the following:

1. Declare a variable called "filename" of type string, assign any value as it will change dynamically during runtime. If you leave it empty, your File System Task will complain it is used as a source/destination and is empty (it doesn't know it will be assigned dynamically).
2. Declare a variable called "sourceDir" and assign **"\\192.168.100.201\f\Backups\"** (variables handle the backslash escaping for you)
3. Declare a variable called "destDir" and assign your destination path ending with a backslash, like **"\\192.168.100.201\f\Destination\"**
4. ForEach Loop Container, go to Collection > expressions
5. Add to the expression "Directory" your variable @[User::sourceDir]
6. Add to the expression "FileSpec" your custom expression but **ending with "*.bak"** (this will allow the filespec to pick the files ignoring anything past the day in the file signature)

   ```
   "582499_backup_" + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART("yyyy", getdate() ) + "_" + RIGHT("0 (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "mm" , getdate() ), 2) + "_" + RIGHT("0 (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "dd" , getdate() ), 2) +".bak"
   ```
7. In Variable Mappings, add your variable **"User::filename"** with **index 0**
8. Add you File System Task to the ForEachLoop Container
9. File System Task: provide your variable **"User::destDir"** as **"DestinationVariable"**, setting IsDestinationVariable to true.
10. File System Task: provide your variable **"User::filename"** as **"SourceVariable"**, setting IsSourcePathVariable to true.
11. Place your test files in the source directory and run in debug mode.
12. You can also right click the ForEachLoop Container and set some breakpoints to see the variable User::filename changing value for the different filenames in the ForEachLoop Enumerator Collection.
13. Now you can deploy your package and create a SQL Server Agent Job to assign a schedule for your package to run and boom. You have a fully automated backup. If the ForEachLoop Container does not find a file to move no problem, it will exit gracefully.