# SSIS - How to copy csv file saved in different folders to a single folder

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

I have a package which save multiple(14) csv files with region name to its respective Region (14) folders. Now i would like to copy all the newly created 14 csv files to a single folder . How can i achieve it through SSIS and can anyone help me achieving it please.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Why not just use a script component and copy all files within those folders to designated folder?

Comment: Any example would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have u tried File system task ?

Comment: no i havent. and as im new to ssis world i would like to go through similar example or project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 ways to copy files between directories in SSIS:

1. **Using Execute Process Task**

you can use a similar command to copy files:

```
COPY c:\Source\*.txt c:\Destination
```

2. **Using a Script Task**

You can write a small script that loop over files in a directory and copy them to a destination

```
string fileName = string.Empty;
string destFile = string.Empty;
string sourcePath = @"C:\test1";
string targetPath = @"C:\test2";   

// Create a new target folder, if necessary. 
if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
}

if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
{
    string wildcard = "*.txt";
    string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, wildcard);

    // Copy the files and overwrite destination files if they already exist. 
    foreach (string s in files)
    {
        fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);
        destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
        System.IO.File.Copy(s, destFile, true);
    }
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("Source path does not exist!");
}
```

*Reference: [Copying all files in SSIS without Foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23158909/copying-all-files-in-ssis-without-foreach)*

3. **Using a File System Task**

You can refer to one of the following links, to get an idea on how `File System Task` works

- [SSIS: File System Task Move and rename files in one step](http://www.rafael-salas.com/2007/03/ssis-file-system-task-move-and-rename.html)
- [Copy Files Using File System Task in SSIS](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/copy-files-using-file-system-task-in-ssis/)
- [Copy Files from One Location to Another and Rename Them after Putting Time Stamp](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/188086/Copy-Files-from-One-Location-to-Another-and-Rename)

Comment: Awesome .... thanks a lot,  I'am going to try the 2nd option. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a script component:

```
DirectoryInfo ParentInfo = new DirectoryInfo(ParentDirectoryPath);
FileInfo[] FileArray = ParentInfo.GetFiles("*",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (FileInfo Fil in FileArray)
{
Fil.CopyTo(Destination Path);
}
```

Not tested, but something like this

Comment: Can you give me an example please? or suggest me to any project link

Comment: Why make it complicated? Just use a command task and run `COPY c:\Source\*.txt c:\Destination`, as per the other answer

Answer (score 0):

You can get way more specific by using C# however you can use a foreach file enumerator.

Map path to parent folder and select traverse subfolders.

Add *.csv as search string.

Map full path to a variable.

Inside foreach add a file system task to copy file.

Comment: I'am new to ssis , hence an example with a screenshot will be helpful brother. can you share an example or a walkthrough project. thanks alot for trying to helping me out.

Comment: IMHO this is far too complicated when you can just use a command task and run `COPY c:\Source\*.txt c:\Destination`, as per the other answer

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I like taking the opportunity to demonstrate the use of file processing via the foreach loop. The learning experience lends use outside of simple copying of files (which we know is not the intended purpose of SSIS). In this case I would use your solution.